# Phone number listed about this phone

Tags: htc

I found a phone that still has the sim card in it but it has been reset to factory settings.  Is there any way to find the phone number associated with that phone (I am sure the owner has a new phone and has had the number changed from the lost phone to the new phone) so I can call it and let the owner know I found their old phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Phone Number on Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130448/get-phone-number-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Settings > about phone > status > sim status

Comment: Consider this: [Get Phone Number on Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/130450)